# Notepad++ Python script name 'notepad' is not defined

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a simple script in Python, in which I am trying to traverse all files in a folder and change them to UTF-8 encoding using Notepad++.

```
import os;
import sys;
import Npp;
Npp.editor.write('Starting\r\n')
filePathSrc="C:\\SomePath"
Npp.editor.write('FilePath: ' + str(filePathSrc) + '\r\n')
try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):
        for fn in files:
            if fn[-4:] == '.txt' or fn[-4:] == '.xml' or fn[-5:] == '.html':
                notepad.open(root + "\\" + fn)
                console.write(root + "\\" + fn + "\r\n")
                notepad.runMenuCommand("Encoding", "Encode in UTF-8")
                notepad.save()
                notepad.close()
                Npp.editor.write('Converted ' + str(fn))
except Exception as ex:
    Npp.editor.write('Error occured\r\n')
    Npp.editor.write(str(ex))
```

However, when I click on Plugins -> Python Script -> Scripts -> MySript, all I get is:

```
Starting
FilePath: C:\SomePath
Error occured
name 'notepad' is not defined
```

When searching the Internet, I have never found anyone with the same problem. All similar problems were caused because people were trying to run the script outside of Notepad++. However, I am getting the error when using Notepad++ plugin directly.

Comment: Where do you think something is assigned to name `notepad`?

Comment: Where is `notepad` defined? Or `console` for that matter. Not in the code that you've posted.

Comment: I supposed it is defined within the plugin itself. The code is just a modification from this post https://pw999.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mass-convert-a-project-to-utf-8-using-notepad/. The names 'console' or 'notepad' are not defined in the code neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/intro.html#npp-module), `editor`, `notepad`, and `console` are all instances defined within the module itself.

You can prefix those objects with `Npp.`, as you have already done for `editor`. A less advised option is to do a `from Npp import *` instead of `import Npp`.

Do you know the encoding of the source files? If so you can just use Python to convert your files to UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you, I am quite a newbie in Python... to avoid future problems, do I always have to explicitly state the module name, when calling its inner objects?

Comment: @Storm: yes that is the preferred way to do it. The reason is that doing an import * can cause problems if there are names in the imported file that clash with those of the importing module, or other imported modules. E.g. if you had a function named `max()` in module `m` and you did an `import * from m` the `max()` from `m` would hide the built-in `max()` function. For that reason it is preferable to import the module, or import specific names from the module, e.g. `from Npp import editor, console, notepad`.